# how to do svg transform in percentage

Tags: svg

I want to center the rect shape with something equivalent to
transform="translate(50% - 100,0)" for example:

```
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100% 100%">
        <g transform="translate(50% - 100,0)">
            <rect width="200" height="100" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I can't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an inner `<svg>` element to do the percentage part via its x attribute then the rest with the `<g>` element as you already have.

I'm not sure what you intend with the viewBox but percentage values are not valid there. Looks like you just don't need that at all.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <svg x="50%" overflow="visible">
        <g transform="translate(-100,0)">
            <rect width="200" height="100" fill="rgb(0,0,255)" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: but rect is fullscreen instead of 200 px width ?

Comment: the rect is 200 units wide, the viewBox says the full screen is 100 units wide. As I said in the answer already I don't understand what you're trying to do with the viewBox. Perhaps to get the rendering you want, you don't need/want it at all.

Comment: My mistake it should have been viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" so your solution works, thanks :)

Comment: No, that's invalid. I guess you don't need a viewBox at all then.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, all articles I read seem to say I need viewbox that's why I created one :)